# Rebuild configuration file when there are no CMake changes

Tags: cmake

I have a project with a configuration file in it.

```
configure_file(version.h.in version/version.h)
```

The same code base is used for multiple build in a day, without cleaning between builds. The `version.h` file will be built the first time the build is run, but subsequent builds will not rebuild (and update the revision number) in the `version.h`.

Is there a way I can force CMake to always rebuild `version.h` regardless of changes, or better yet based on a change (or lack of change) in a subversion revision number?

Comment: Whenever your input file changes, a re-run of `cmake` is automatically forced when you run your build program (`make`, `ninja`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure CMake solution @stevelorimer's answer is great and the way to go. But, you can also look to your CI system (if you have one) and your RCS. You asked:

> Is there a way I can force CMake to always rebuild `version.h` regardless of changes...?

The simplest way is to just `touch` your `version.h.in` as part of your build process. If you next call `cmake`, `version.h` will be rebuilt. If you call (let's say) `make`, it will re-run cmake and rebuild `version.h`.

> ...or better yet based on a change (or lack of change) in a subversion revision number?

If you have access to your svn repo you can add a [pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) to your repo that modifies `version.h.in` (or even `version.h`) in situ, and adds it to the commit. While possibly more complicated than the CMake solution, it has the added benefit of not using SVN or CMake to determine the revision, possibly allowing other tooling to scrape the revision.

Comment: I was trying for a pure CMake solution, like that provided by @SteveLorimer, but realized that the issue is caused due to our build system checkout model (which should soon be moving to Git), so modding a build launch script turned out to be far easier than modifying numerous version files and targets. In the end, I think that Steve has the more CMakish answer, but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues you need to overcome to have this work.

- When cmake is run any version information you extract from subversion is baked into the generated build files, and so becomes static.
- Cmake is only rerun if it detects the generated build files have become out of date (eg: if a `CMakeLists.txt` file is updated)
- You can create a `custom_target` which will be run every time you build (from the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html): `"The target has no output file and is ALWAYS CONSIDERED OUT OF DATE"`) which generates the file, but that will force you to rebuild your generated version file *every time*.

Here is an approach which overcomes all of the above hurdles:

First, create a library which will contain the compiled version information.

```
add_library(version STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version_gen.cc)
```

Now, add an artificial dependency between the library and a `custom_target` called `gen_version`

```
add_dependencies(version gen_version)
```

This will force `gen_version` to be run **before** building the `version` library.

Now create a `custom_target` called `gen_version` which will generate the version information:

```
add_custom_target(
    gen_version
    ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen_version.cmake)
```

This custom target is added to the `ALL` target, and will be run **every** time you build. It will execute another cmake script called `gen_version.cmake`

This is the first trick. We get cmake to execute a subprocess and run a new cmake script on each build, in which the required version information is calculated anew each build.

The next trick is to call `configure_file` with a **temporary output file,** and **only update the real version file if necessary**. This prevents the need to recompile when the version doesn't change.

In the below example I show obtaining the version information from git - you can swap this for your subversion method.

**`gen_version.cmake`:**

```
# obtain the git version
execute_process(
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE   ${VERSION}
    COMMAND           git rev-parse --short HEAD
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    )

# configure the version file, but output to a temporary location
configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version_gen.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version_gen.cc.tmp
    )

# compare with the real version file
execute_process(
    COMMAND
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version_gen.cc.tmp
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version_gen.cc
    RESULT_VARIABLE
        VERSION_NEEDS_UPDATING

    OUTPUT_QUIET
    ERROR_QUIET
)

# update the real version file if necessary
if(VERSION_NEEDS_UPDATING)
    execute_process(
        COMMAND
            ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version_gen.cc.tmp
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version_gen.cc
    )
endif()

set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/version_gen.cc
    PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```

Comment: For a CMake only solution, I like this, but is the file comparison necessary? Can't the output of `configure_file()` just be a throwaway?

Comment: @nega I'm not sure what you're suggesting? The point behind using a temporary file as the output for `configure_file` is to prevent the target file (`version_gen.cc`) being updated unnecessarily, which has the consequence of causing the object file to be rebuilt. One way or another you're going to have to figure out if the version info *now* is different to that in the generated version file the last time the build was run. One way is to do a file comparison. Another would be to read the generated file, search for the version info, and then check if they are different.

Comment: Right, I was thinking in a purely versioned manor. Even a non-versioned throwaway, would need to be compared to prevent recompiling based on timestamp (assuming you cared :).

Comment: @nega yes, but of course it will typically be significantly faster to compare the file than to rebuild it, and relink every application which links in the version information

Comment: Yup, yup, I agree

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I followed the example and it worked perfectly. However, I ended up going with @nega's answer, because rerunning cmake every build, even to check if a target file has changed, annoys developers.

Comment: @the_storyteller note the invocation of cmake which generates the build files is *not* rerun every build. Only a subprocess with this small script is run, as part of the usual build process. It is automatic, run as part of building, and doesn't affect the generated build files.